# Double integral over a region $D$ - Which are the limits?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

When we want to calculate an integral over $D=\{-1\leq x,y,\leq 1, \ x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ then we take at the integrals the limits $-1\leq x\leq 1$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$, i.e. $$\iint_D=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, dydx$$ right?

When we want to calculate an integral over $D=\{0\leq x,y,\leq 1, \ x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ then do we take at the integrals the limits $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $-\sqrt{1-x^2}\leq y\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$ or $0\leq x\leq 1$ and $0\leq y\leq \sqrt{1-x^2}$ ? Do we have then. $$\iint_D=\int_{0}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, dydx\ \ \ \text{ or } \ \ \ \iint_D=\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, dydx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your first question, you are right.

Concerning the second one, since both $x$ and $y$ belong to $[0,1]$, the integral is$$\int_0^1\int_0^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx.$$It is perhaps easier to do it in polar coordinates:$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^1f\bigl(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)\bigr)r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Comment: Ok! And if we have $D=\{0\leq x,\leq 1, \ -1\leq y\leq 1 \ \ x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ ? Do we have then $$\iint_D=\int_{0}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, dydx$$ ? Or what is then in that case?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: In general we take the intersection of all inequalities to get the limits of the integrals, or not? Or is there also an other rule that we have to consider?

Comment: That is what I do.

Comment: Great! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: If we have $H=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\mid -1\leq x\leq 1,\ 0\leq y\leq1, \ x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$ then do we have that $$\iint_H\, dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\, ddrd\theta$$ ? Or which is the interval of $\theta$ ?

Comment: That is another question. I suggest that you post it as such.